# Is there any way to schema compare with a SQL CE database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce, schema-compare

I've been developing a WPF desktop application that uses a SQL Server Express 2012 database. I'm now thinking of trying SQL Server CE, in an attempt to simplify database install/deployment, and wondered if there was any way I can "populate" the CE database schema and data, either from the existing SQL Express database or its corresponding VS2012 database project. I've tried the "schema compare" option on the database project, but I can't seem to create a new connection to the sdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use my SQL Server Toolbox VS addin and standalone app (free and open source) to both do chema compare and data and schema migration.